# How to rewrite a folder in WordPress?

Tags: permalinks, themes, url-rewriting, htaccess

I'm using "The7" theme and don't want to use the standard Portfolio archive template. I have used the default template to create a page that looks great, let's call it `/our-portfolio/`.

Currently the permalink structure for portfolio items is `/portfolio/item-1/`.

Though the theme allows me to change the slug for the portfolio, if I do this, the `/our-portfolio/` page will be replaced with the Portfolio Archive page, which I don't want.

So my question is, can I use a rewrite rule or a plugin to rewrite `/portfolio/item-1/` to `/our-portfolio/item-1/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be mixing up a couple of concepts here. Use the new template page you made and name it archive-portfolio.php. This will display all portfolio post types in your new template at `yoursite.com/portfolio` and the url for the portfolio items should take care of itself. They will still be at `yoursite.com/portfolio/item1` so no need to change the permalinks - or slug. If you want to change the single item display you need to edit `single.php`, change the name to `single-{post_type}`.php and it will be used automatically

Comment: Thanks, the new page only uses the default template and is made in Visual Composer, so it's not as simple as making a new file. I am assuming there is no way to do this with redirects?

Comment: I see. There probably is but not my expertise. Sorry. If I have time to look into it I'll let you know